Compute sessions in Azure studio ai won't start
I can't run a compute session within a prompt flow in azure studio ai(only works in east US hub, my west US and sweden central ones don't work), even when changing to different types of VMs. Eventually it times out and drops this error:
Session status messages: Custom application deployment failed after retry with new compute session4e29f9050a8b, abort session creation for Session ID: 01f23f34-c080-4384-b5a4-b0408de1307b.

Trace ID : bfc959ef-cd06-469d-baac-3caa02d8aef5

here's what I got
